# Android -- how to strech columns of Tablelayout without streching its children

Tags: android

as the title means, I want my tablelayout to evenly assign each column's width and the child of  each column be centered inside the column. Setting `android:stretchColumns="*"` also, however,  streches the child inside each column.

any ideas for hacking this issue?

using horizontal Linearlayout to  imitate a tablerow is acceptable, but I also have no idea how to get a Linearlayout to arrange its children evenly :(

pls help, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hack needed. :-)
Simply set the layout_width of the children to wrap_content instead of fill_parent, or to a fixed value. Set layout_gravity to center or center_horizontal.

EDIT: Code added.

Try this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:shrinkColumns="*" android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: thank u for reply, I am sorry, I can still not get it to work, use Button widget instead of Textview :(

Comment: Does your TableLayout reside inside a view element with layout_width:wrap_content? That is the only reason I can see for this not to work...

Comment: If this answer did not work for you, why did you accept it as an answer?

Comment: Also did you get it working with a button widget? I to am having the same problem.